# Referential transparency in dplyr::filter: making column name variable

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, referential-transparency

### Core question (what it seems to boil down to)

How do I construct a call to `rlang::quo` with the **"left"** instead of the "right" side of the expression being referentially transparent

Taken from the help page of `rlang::quo`, this works

```
quo(foo(!! quo(bar)))
# <quosure: global>
# ~foo(~bar)
```

while this doesn't:

```
quo(!! quo(foo)(bar))
# Error in (function (x)  : attempt to apply non-function
```

### Question put into a bit more context

`dplyr::mutate` allows "both sides of an expression" to be variable in the sense that both expression parts can be made referentially transparent ([see vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)):

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(89234)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, 3), value = rpois(9, 10))

c_id <- as.name("id")
c_value <- as.name("value")
# NOTE: in our prototyping, actual columns names are often subject to
# change (e.g. `id` might become `id_global`), thus I would like to stay 
# as flexible as possible in all of my subsequent `dplyr` calls.

my_multiply <- function(x, by) x * by

df %>% mutate(!!c_value := my_multiply(!!c_value, 10))
#   id value
# 1  1    70
# 2  2    90
# 3  3   130
# 4  1    80
# 5  2    80
# 6  3   120
# 7  1   140
# 8  2   120
# 9  3   110
```

How can I realize the same/something similar in `dplyr::filter` the focus being able to make the column name ("left side") referentially transparten/flexible.

I would like to ideally end up with something like this (pseudo code):

```
v_id <- 1
df %>% filter(!!c_id :== v_id)
```

### What I tried

I'm aware that `dplyr::filter` differs to `dplyr::mutate` regarding the type of expressions they expect. So based on [the vignette](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) I came up with this version where the entire expression to be evaluated is passed as an argument:

```
my_filter <- function(x, expr) {
  quo_expr <- enquo(expr)
  print(quo_expr)
  x %>% filter(!!quo_expr)
}
v_id <- 1
my_filter(df, id == v_id)
# <quosure: global>
# ~id == v_id
#   id value
# 1  1     7
# 2  1     8
# 3  1    14
```

However, that "forces" me to really use the actual column name while I would like to use the reference `c_id`:

```
my_filter(df, c_id == v_id)
# <quosure: global>
# ~c_id == v_id
# [1] id    value
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I'm basically at loss of how to construct a call to `dplyr::quo` or `dplyr::enquo` where the left part contains the **evaluated** reference of the column name while the right part contains the **non-evaluated* reference of the logical query to be evaluated:

```
my_filter <- function(x, left, right) {
  quo_expr <- quo(quo(!!left) == right)
  print(quo_expr)
  x %>% filter(!!quo_expr)
}
my_filter(df, c_id, v_id)

# <quosure: frame>
# ~quo(id) >= right
# [1] id    value
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Put another way, I think the quosure should end up being `~id == right` and I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

With some help form another community I was able to piece it together to arrive at a much simpler solution:

```
df %>% filter((!! c_id) == v_id)
#   id value
# 1  1     7
# 2  1     8
# 3  1    14
```

So it simply comes down to wrapping the call to `!!` with parentheses!

Using `!!` without parentheses would not work because `!` has low operator precedence so it basically captures everything to its right and thus complains:

```
df %>% filter(!! c_id == v_id)
# [1] id    value
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

What's going on here behind the scenes is that the logical operation actually being carried out is `! (!c_id == v_id)`. Since `!c_id == v_id` is `TRUE` the entire expression returns `FALSE`. Thus, we're actually running `df %>% filter(FALSE) which is clearly not what we wanted ;-)